# How to resolve certificate for <*> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*]?

Tags: java, curl, http-post

I am trying to upload a file into file observer in ASM topology. But it is giving this error when the httpclient is executing. Here is the full error:-

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute ApplicationRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:813) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:800) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:346) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1340) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1329) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    at com.verizon.VcpOpsFileUploadApplication.main(VcpOpsFileUploadApplication.java:20) ~[classes/:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Certificate for <noi-topology.noi.apps.cluster1.ibm.dfwt5g.lab> doesn't match any of the subject alternative names: [*.apps.cluster1.ibm.dfwt5g.lab]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:507) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:437) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108) ~[httpclient-4.5.13.jar:4.5.13]
    at com.verizon.controller.ASMFileUploadController.uploadFile(ASMFileUploadController.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.verizon.VcpOpsFileUploadApplication.run(VcpOpsFileUploadApplication.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:810) ~[spring-boot-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
    ... 5 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 2):

Wildcard certificates are only for one level. `*.example.com` will match `foo.example.com` and `bar.example.com`, but will not match `foo.bar.example.com`.

Your `*.apps.cluster1.ibm.dfwt5g.lab` wildcard certificate will not match `noi-topology.noi.apps.cluster1.ibm.dfwt5g.lab` because `*` doesn't match `noi-topology.noi`.

You need a wildcard certificate for `*.noi.apps.cluster1.ibm.dfwt5g.lab`, or need to change the domain name to e.g. `noi-topology.apps.cluster1.ibm.dfwt5g.lab`.

Comment: Thank you @Andreas I am able to access that url with that I have content type error

Comment: @AmanpreetKaur That sounds like an entirely different problem, so I suggest you create an entirely different question, explaining your new problem.